# Can someone explain this sentence?

Tags: american-english, british-english

"The fastest economic growth **in more than 30 years**"

Does it mean that country experienced the fastest economic growth relative to any year within the 30 year period?

Link :

http://www.nytimes.com/2000/01/28/us/state-union-president-clinton-state-union-strongest-it-has-ever-been.html

Yes, It's a very old article. i came across that sentence on ludwig. So i am kinda curious about this. If you find that article too tedious to read, you may opt to answer the second example.

Second example:

"Gold is set for the biggest monthly gain **in more than four years** after a weaker dollar and low rates fueled its surge to a record."

Link:

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-07-31/gold-set-for-best-month-in-four-years-after-record-breaking-gain?utm_content=business&utm_source=facebook&cmpid=socialflow-facebook-business&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=socialflow-organic

Comment: There was a period of time during which the country's economy was growing faster than at any other time in the past 30 years.

Answer (score 1):

The first example means that at no time in more than thirty years was economic growth greater than at the time of the speech. The article doesn't specify that it is comparing the most recent year to previous one-year periods, though that may be what was meant.

The second example is simpler because it specifies "monthly gain". It means that the next figure for monthly gain will be greater than any other figure for monthly gain occurring in the last four years.